# Signal missed by child process

Tags: c, linux, process, signals

To initialize an application the parent process forks 3 child processes, the child processes then set up their signal handlers and signal back to the parent that they are ready to start activity. SIGUSR1 signal is used to achieve this.

The parent process in the meanwhile is waiting for these signals from the child processes. As soon as a signal is received, the parent matches its pid with the child pids it has stored and increments a counter. Once the parent knows that go-ahead signals from all child processes have been received it starts to send each one of them a SIGUSR1 signal to indicate to start activity.

The fact that all signals are sent from the parent for each child is verified; however, most times one of the child processes misses the signal. Over multiple trials, I have identified that the process to which the parent sends the signal first, misses it. However sometimes it also occurs that all child processes miss their signals. I have also used the 'strace' tool to check the flow of all signals but still can't seem to identify why the child processes fail to catch the signals sent by the parent.

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Describing code in text is very ambiguous, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us instead, and if there's output then please provide the actual and expected output as well.

Comment: There are so many things that could be going wrong it is impossible for us to help you without at least an MCVE, as Joachim said.  How do you know which child sent each signal?  How do you know that the parent has successfully sent each of the children a signal?  We can't begin to guess the answers to such questions without seeing the code.

Comment: its in signals nature to be unreliable :)

Answer (score 0):

`SIGUSR1` and other POSIX signals are not queued. If the process has already one pending, any other signals will be discarded.

You can avoid this by using "realtime signals". You use them just like you use the standard POSIX signals; the first one is named `SIGRTMIN+0`, and the last one is named `SIGRTMAX-0`. If you use `sigqueue()`, you can even attach one `int` (or a void pointer) as a payload.

POSIX realtime signals are queued (up to a limit), so you are less likely to lose them.

However, I would not use signals for tracking the child processes. I would use pipes, with the child having the write ends, and parent having the read ends, and all descriptors marked for close-on-exec using [`fcntl(descriptor, O_SETFD, O_CLOEXEC)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) on each.

The children update the parent on their status via one-byte messages. If the child exits or executes another program, the parent will see it as end-of-file condition ([`read()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) returning zero). If the parent exits, the write end will become unwritable for the child write end, and any attempt at writing to the pipe will fail with `EPIPE` error. (It will also raise the `SIGPIPE` signal, so you might wish to use [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) to ignore the `SIGPIPE` signal.)

The parent can monitor the child process statuses in parallel using [`select()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) or [`poll()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). Whenever a child process sends data, or exits or executes another program (which closes the write end of the pipe), the parent descriptor (read end of the pipe) will become readable. Personally, I also mark the parent descriptors nonblocking using `fcntl(rfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)`, so that if there is a glitch, instead of blocking on a mis-read, the read on a parent will just fail with `EWOULDBLOCK` in errno.

If you want bidirectional data flow, it is easiest to use an additional pipe for each child, parent writing and child reading from it.

It is also possible to use unnamed Unix domain datagram sockets (created via [`socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0, fds)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketpair.2.html). (See also [man 2 socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) and [man 7 unix](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) for details on the parameters.) Also use `fcntl(fds[0], F_SETFL, O_CLOEXEC)` and `fcntl(fds[1], F_SETFL, O_CLOEXEC)` to make the descriptors close-on-exec, just as in the pipe case, too.

The problem with Unix domain socket pairs (of any type -- `SOCK_STREAM`, `SOCK_DGRAM`, `SOCK_SEQPACKET`), is that they can contain *ancillary data*. This *ancillary data* can contain additional file descriptors, which are a limited commodity. If there is a possibility of an untrustworthy or nasty child process, it might kill its parent by sending it a few thousand file descriptors. For security, the parent process should monitor what it receives from the child process, and if it contains ancillary data, immediately close that descriptor (as the child process is obviously hostile!), and if any file descriptors were provided, close those too. You can only avoid this if you trust your child processes as much as you trust your original process for not doing anything nefarious.

Securing unix domain sockets is not hard, but checking each received  datagram or receive for ancillary data is a couple of dozen additional lines of code.. Pipes are simpler.